# AJAX post data is not recognized

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a made an AJAX request.

Here is its setting:

```
    $.ajax({

        data : { id : 25 },
        dataType : 'json',
        contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
type  : 'POST',
        // the rest of the setting
        });
```

And here is the server side:

```
header("contentType=application/json");

// and then the rest of the request
```

Everything works. Data is returned through JSON and no problem. But the $_POST is not filled with any data, though when I check the ajax request log through firebug I see that it sends the id...what could be the problem? The problem exists when I set the contentType header and dataType...

I also have set `Allow Origin` header but the problem is not solved...

I also have checked the data with `$_POST` and `$_REQUEST`

I use LARAVEL framework...

Comment: Show the rest of your settings.

Comment: I apologize; I should been more clear.  Firstly, with your added JS.. I see nothing wrong with it.  Whatever the problem may be may be server side.  Please show all of your code.  Otherwise, there is insufficient information to solve this problem.

Comment: @MT-Developer Please check the update of my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The default method type for jQuery's `ajax` method is `GET`. Try to set the method type to `POST` in your settings, like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',               // <<<<
    data : { id : 25 },
    dataType : 'json',
    contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    // the rest of the setting
});
```

For more information about `ajax` method, please refer [here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

**Update**

I think it would be better not to specify the `contentType`. The official documentation says:

> contentType (default: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8')
>    
> **When sending data to the server, use this content type**. Default is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8", **which is fine for most cases**. If you explicitly pass in a content-type to $.ajax(), then it is always sent to the server (even if no data is sent). The W3C XMLHttpRequest specification dictates that the charset is always UTF-8; specifying another charset will not force the browser to change the encoding.

Answer (score 0):

you should check with $_GET to see if the data is there. 
if you are not explicitly defining any method by which to send the data, then by default the GET method is used. 
either set the method as POST or retrieve the data through $_GET to see if it is there.

Answer (score 0):

add **type** in ajax

```
$.ajax({

data : { id : 25 },
dataType : 'json',
type :'POST'
contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
// the rest of the setting

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are not passing **type** so it is a **Get** Request by default, check in `$_GET[]` or add type **POST** in the ajax call.

Answer (score -1):

you miss to declare type POST use as following way

```
$.ajax({

data : { id : 25 },
dataType : 'json',
type :'POST',
contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
// the rest of the setting
```

});

Comment: jQuery's `ajax` method doesn't accept `method` property.

Comment: sorry it's my mistake it should be 'type'